# Internet explorer problem opening same url

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, refresh

I have quite a serious problem with Internet Explorer.

I am developing a Flex application (though that is irrelevant as I have verified the problem is with IE).

In the application, I need to perform a http service request by submitting some data.  This works fine no problem... the first time!  When submitting the same url a second time (for another request), it seems that IE recognises that it is the same page and doesn't bother actually doing it.

I checked just submitting the url (without the Flex application calling it) and the same problem is there.  I checked in Firefox and, lo and behold, working no problem!

You can see this behaviour if you go to google.com and then highlight the address bar url and hit enter again.  There is a noticeable difference between doing that and pressing F5 (to refresh).

Does anyone know a way to force IE to look up the url each time (like it's supposed to).  I've looked in the advanced settings but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, don't worry ;)

What you do is take your URL and add `?x=RAND`, where RAND is some random number that you add to the string. This will make the URL different without actually affecting it, which completely avoids your problem :)

Comment: Very nice idea.  Simple and effective :)  Thanks!

Comment: Usually what I do is take the current timestamp in milliseconds and use that - more entropy :p